# neo4j return json from traversal in unmanaged extension like cypher rest api pattern

Tags: json, neo4j, cypher, traversal

I have written an unmanaged extension with a traversal and I have an Iterable  as a result of traverse that I need to convert in the same json format of the cypher rest api output. In this way I can link the unmanaged extension with neo4j php library I'm utilizing.
Where is the code that accomplish this in the neo4j server community edition or what class/method I need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as easy as generating the JSON of the [transactional endpoint](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-transactional.html), or the old [cypher endpoint](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-cypher.html) (depending on which your library uses).

It makes sense to stream though too, if you return a  lot of data,
using an [approach like this](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/streaming-cypher/blob/master/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/extension/streaming/cypher/CypherHttpService.java#L39).